# Asp menu not showing horizontaly on page load for few seconds?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am using asp menu in my application which is in horizontal direction as you can see in image.

[image]

When i move from one page to another or refresh any page it shows all the menu elements in vertical direction for a while and it disturbs my application structure as in the following image.

[image]

How can i overcome this problem? I have changed its all overflow properties with several methods but nothing is working. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Some code would help us to help you...

Comment: can you share aspx and code behind?

Comment: There were the same topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240873/how-to-get-rid-of-ugly-aspmenu-flickering Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to my page also. Somehow this is related to server speed. In my case, when this happened the pages were taking too long to load. After a while, when pages were loading at normal speed the issue went away.

There was some mention of this in another thread (connection speed between client and server). I confirm this to be the case at least for me.